# C# - Operand error

Tags: c#

I have a console application that is giving the error:

operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'program3_Sales.Books' and 'program3_Sales.Books'. The error is occurring on this line of code (the red error line is under the s1 + s2). Any ideas of why I am getting this error? Thanks.

```
Books total = s1 + s2 + s3;
```

Here is my code:

```
namespace Book_Sales
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Books s1 = new Books("Cats Meow", 2000, 0.20);
            Books s2 = new Books("Bender", 4000);
            Books s3 = new Books("Carter");
            Books total = s1 + s2 + s3;
            Display(s1);
            Display(s2);
            Display(s3);
            DisplayTotal(total);
        }
        public static void Display(Books s)
        {


            Console.Write("{0} had sales totaling {1}.", s.Name, s.SalesAmount);
            Console.WriteLine(" Commission rate is {0}; commision value is {1}.",
                s.getRate(), s.Commission);
        }
        public static void DisplayTotal(Books s)
        {

            Console.Write("Total sales: {0}", s.SalesAmount.ToString("C"));
        }
    }

    class Books
    {
        readonly double RATE;
        private double salesAmount;
        private double commission;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double SalesAmount { get; set; }
        public double Commission { get; set; }
        public double rate { get; set; }

        public Books(string name, double salesAmount, double rate)
        {
            Name = name;
            RATE = rate;
            SalesAmount = salesAmount;


        }

        public Books (string name)
            : this(name, 0, 0)
        {
        }

        public Books(string name, double salesAmount)
            : this(name, salesAmount, 0)
        {
        }

        public double getRate()
        {
            return commission = salesAmount * rate;
        }
        //methods
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not clear in the error message for you? What result do you expect to get?

Comment: As the error message tells you, you can't add objects like those together.  Tell us what you're trying to get, and we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: Why the result is of a `Books` type not `Superbook` instead?

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't it be something like

```
double total = s1.SalesAmount + s2.SalesAmount + s3.SalesAmount;
```

As others have mentioned, you could overload the '+' operator but even then total would need to be a double, not of type Book

Comment: I've deleted the... book... of comments that were here. ;)

Comment: @Andrew Barber♦: correction: it was 2 books in one book of comments

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the `+` operator:

```
public static double operator+(Book b1, Book b2) {
    return b1.SalesAmount + b2.SalesAmount;
}
```

..you would probably be better off adding it manually though.. as it makes more sense:

```
var result = b1.SalesAMount + b2.SalesAmount + b3.SalesAmount;
```

..etc.